# Node JS, why fs.statSync() no need await

Tags: node.js

In NodeJS

Read a file detail is a action absolutely takes time

so, Why this code no need async/await, does statSync block the event loop until it done, so, it no need await ?

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
try {
  const stats = fs.statSync('/Users/joe/test.txt');
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: *does statSync block the event loop until it done* - yes. Also `await` works only on promises, `statSync` doesn't return a promise

Comment: but how it block the event loop?

Comment: In the same way as `while (true) {}` blocks it

Comment: *"Read a file detail is a action absolutely takes time"* – this seems to suggest that you think every operation that "takes time" is automatically asynchronous. But that's not the case, *everything* takes time (even if it's often just nanoseconds.) Operations are by default blocking regardless of how long they take. Making them asynchronous is what requires effort.

Comment: @Konrad it seem correct

Answer (score 1):

In Node.js
fs.statSync() is a synchronous operation. When you call fs.statSync(), it blocks the event loop until the operation is completed and returns the result synchronously. Therefore, you don't need to use async/await with fs.statSync() because it doesn't return a promise that needs to be awaited asynchronously

Comment: How it block the event loop?